How to get rid of clerk warning in console?
I am using clerk, and I keep seeing this warning during development in my console:
Clerk: Clerk has been loaded with development keys. Development instances have strict usage limits and should not be used when deploying your application to production. Learn more: https://clerk.com/docs/deployments/overview Error Component Stack
    at ClerkContextProvider (ClerkContextProvider.tsx:20:11)
    at ClerkProviderBase (ClerkProvider.tsx:11:11)
    at Hoc (useMaxAllowedInstancesGuard.tsx:28:5)
    at ClerkNextOptionsProvider (NextOptionsContext.tsx:18:11)
    at ClientClerkProvider (ClerkProvider.tsx:27:11)
    at ClerkProvider [Server] (<anonymous>)
    at RootLayout [Server] (<anonymous>)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:48:5)
    at RedirectBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:79:9)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:33:5)
    at NotFoundBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:119:3)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (dev-root-not-found-boundary.tsx:20:3)
    at ReactDevOverlay (ReactDevOverlay.tsx:91:3)
    at HotReload (hot-reloader-client.tsx:523:3)
    at Router (app-router.tsx:215:9)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (error-boundary.tsx:69:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (error-boundary.tsx:190:3)
    at AppRouter (app-router.tsx:632:3)
    at ServerRoot (app-index.tsx:180:32)
    at Root (app-index.tsx:208:17)

I run my project using bun run dev normally, to start development environment:
// package.json
"scripts: {
  "dev": "next dev --turbopack",
}

And my environment variables are already set:
# .env.development
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY= "pk_test_*****..etc"
CLERK_SECRET_KEY= "sk_test_****...etc"

And my root layout is already set with clerk provider:
import './globals.css'
import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/nextjs'

// ...

export default async function RootLayout({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
        <html>
          <body>
             {children}
          </body>
        </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  )
}

But I keep seeing this warning in my console

This warning always happens in all cases, when I visit my site on:
http://localhost:3000/
http://192.168.1.118:3000/ # (my private ip)

How can I stop this warning?

You can always override console.warn globally to selectively ignore Clerk's development warning:
const warn = console.warn
console.warn = (...args) => {
  const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV
  const clerkStartMsg = 'Clerk: Clerk has been loaded with development keys.'
  if (
    NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
    typeof args[0] === 'string' &&
    args[0].startsWith(clerkStartMsg)
  ) {
    return
  }
  warn.apply(console, args)
}



Where do you put this in a nextjs project?

please add a complete answer so I can mark this question as complete

I work at Clerk. Currently, there is no way to get rid of this warning. We added the warning because there were many instances where our users would deploy development keys to production and this would result in a less secure app that would be locked to new sign ups after a small number of users and require a stressful environment migration. Anything we can do to avoid users having to go through this makes a big difference.
It does only show up once per time that you run your app and doesn't appear every page load or re-render though!

Thanks for replying. please add an option to suppress this warning, maybe on the ClerkProvider, ex: <ClerkProvider spressDevelopmentKeysWarning />

While I understand some of the motivation for adding this. PLEASE let us disable it somehow. To me this is annoying to such a degree that if you force this on developers, I would consider ripping out Clerk entirely. To me it's incredibly rude that you pollute the console in which we work all day (e.g. back-scroll is broken in the console because the entire stacktrace gets printed, etc).

PS: In my case this is for a react native app where the actual terminal output/log (i.e. not the browser console) is important, and you annoy me there.

Place this regular expression in the console's filter control:
-/^(Clerk: Clerk has been loaded with development keys)/


Great thanks ..
